# Execute mysql Querys with jQuery/Ajax and PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP Script which lists all Applications from a Databse in a HTML Table. In an own row I want two buttons. Accept and decline
Accept should set the status to "accepted" for the id i klicked on accept.
The Same for decline.
This should update the status in the mysql database.

My Script at the moment:

```
    echo '<table border="1">';
echo '<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Alter</th>
<th>E-Mail</th>
<th>KD</th>
<th>Steam</th>
<th>Spiele</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Accept</th>
<th>Decline</th>
</tr>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis))
   {
   echo '<tr>';
 echo '<td>' . $row->id . '</td>';
 echo '<td>' . $row->name . '</td>';
 echo '<td>' . $row->age . '</td>';
 echo '<td>' . $row->mail . '</td>';
 echo '<td>' . $row->kd . '</td>';
 echo '<td>' . $row->steam . '</td>';
 echo '<td>' . $row->spiele . '</td>';
 echo '<td>' . $row->status . '</td>';
 echo '</tr>';
   }
   echo '</table>';
```

I want my script to be dynamic, so I don't have to refresh the page  after every change. Is it possible to do this with jQuery or Ajax? If yes, how do I do it?

Comment: In which event you want to show this data?

Answer (score 0):

1. change `<tr>` to `<tr class="clickable" data-id="' . $row->id . '">`
2. attach an event handler to `tr.clickable`

   `$('tr.clickable').on('click', function(element) {
       $.get('changeStatus.php?' + $(element).data('id'));
   });`
3. improve the code above

Comment: kannst du mir das bitte etwas genauer erklären? Ich komm da noch nicht ganz mit. Was soll in der "changeStatus.php" stehen?

Comment: You cannot access the database using JS, thus, you need a serverside script which `UPDATE`s the rows. If you don't have a clue how to use Ajax/jQuery, you should use google and go through example code and tutorials first.

Comment: Yeah, I know, that JS can't access the Databse.
Okay, I will read me a bit into it.